# Map isotopic to identity is orientation preserving

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, orientation

Let $M$ be an $n$-dimensional orientable and compact smooth manifold and $f:M\to M$ be a smooth map isotopic to the identity map. Is it true that $f$ is orientation preserving?

Comment: The manifold has to be orientable to begin with!

Comment: In the compact case, it is enough to see what such a map does to the top de Rham cohomology group.

Comment: If you think of orientations as being equivalent to (classes of) volume forms, this becomes almost obvious - you've constructed a homotopy between two volume forms, now by the intermediate value theorem...

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Thanks. I edited.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Isn't there a more elementary proof? I've just started studying differential topology

Answer (score 3):

Orientations on a smooth $n$-manifold are equivalent to (equivalence classes of) nonvanishing $n$-forms, where $\omega \sim \eta$ if there's a positive smooth function $f$ with $f\omega = \eta$. Equivalently, because $C^\infty(M,\Bbb R^+)$ is connected, $\omega$ and $\eta$ are equivalent iff they are in the same path component of the space of nonvanishing $n$-forms.

Now pick an orientation $[\omega]$. If $f_t$ is a homotopy through diffeomorphisms between the identity and $f$, then $f_t^*\omega$ is a path in the space of $n$-forms between $\omega$ and $f^*\omega$; and hence, they're equivalent orientations.

Note that there is no good way of talking about whether or not a smooth map is orientation-preserving or reversing, because $d_pf$ needn't be an isomorphism - which is the condition you need to make sense of "$f$ is orientation-(blah) at $p$". This is why we restrict to diffeomorphisms here.

Comment: I think it does need to be an isotopy, so that $f_t^* \omega$ is nonzero for all $t$. For example, certainly any diffeomorphism $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is homotopic to the identity, but some of them don't preserve orientation.

Comment: @Pedro: Sorry, I meant homotopic through diffeomorphisms. Your example is correct otherwise.

Comment: What's the difference between an isotopy and a homotopy through diffeomorphisms, in this case?

Comment: @Pedro: Oops, you're right. Call it a thinko. (If I wanted to be super pedantic, I would tell you that an isotopy demands $M \times I \to M$ is smooth, but that's obviously not what I or the OP meant.) I appreciate the corrections.

Comment: No problem, I'm just asking because I never quite understood what various people meant by isotopy.

Comment: Hi, I just opened a bounty. Could you explain to me the conclusion "then $f_t^*\omega$ is a path in the space of $n$-forms between $\omega$ and $f^*\omega$; and hence, they're equivalent orientations"?

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your definition of orientation is, it gives a continuous homomorphism $\operatorname{Diffeo}(M)\to\{\pm 1\}$. So an isotopy gives a continuous map $[0;1]\to\{\pm 1\}$ which is constant (by intermediate value thm).

(Of course, one have to check that the map $\operatorname{Diffeo}(M)\to\{\pm 1\}$ is indeed continuous — and the details depend on the definition of 'orientation-preserving' you're using.)