# $M$ oriented surface, diffeomorphism $f:M \to M$ is $C^2$-homotopic to the identity, $f$ preserves orientation

Tags: real-analysis, integration, differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, surfaces

> Let $M$ be an oriented surface. If a diffeomorphism $f:M \to M$ is
>   $C^2$-homotopic to the identity, then $f$ preserves orientation

The only question I found related to this is [Map isotopic to identity is orientation preserving](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1517877/map-isotopic-to-identity-is-orientation-preserving)

I couldn't understand the provided answer. My book's definition of an oriented surface is "**M is orientable if it admits an oriented atlas.**", but it looks like this answer is using something about volume forms, which also can be used to define orientabiity, as I found: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability#Orientability_of_manifolds

I'm trying to prove without using the concepts of volume forms, but if they're needed, then I'd be glad if someone could explain better to me the given answer.

Since it involves diffeomorphisms and homotopy, could it possibly be related to homotopy equivalences?

Using the classic definitions, $f$ being homotopic to the identity, then it can be deformed smoothly to the identity function. How it affects the atlas?  I guess that since $f$ is from $M$ to itself and it's homotopic to the identity, it's intuitive that it'll preserve orientation, but I don't have any idea in how to prove it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**:  You're confusing orientability of $M$ (which is given) and the question of whether a diffeomorphism is orientation-preserving. Without loss of generality, assume $M$ is connected, and start with compatible orientations on all the tangent spaces. Fix any point $x\in M$, and consider the invertible linear maps $d(f_t)_x\colon T_x M\to T_{f_t(x)}M$ as $t$ varies from $0$ to $1$. What can you say? (Then why does it work for all $x\in M$?)

**EDIT**: Here's an alternative argument. (It's always difficult to guess what you know and feel comfortable with.) Since $M$ is orientable, there is a volume form, i.e., a nowhere-zero $n$-form $\omega$; so, in particular, we may take  $\int_M \omega>0$. Now, homotopic maps $f,g\colon M\to M$ have the property that $\int_M f^*\omega = \int_M g^*\omega$. In particular, if $f$ is homotopic to the identity, then we have $\int_M f^*\omega = \int_M \omega > 0$. But by the degree formula (see, e.g., Guillemin and Pollack), $\int_M f^*\omega = \deg(f)\int_M \omega$, so $\deg (f) = 1$, which says that $f$ is orientation-preserving.

Comment: What is a compatible orientation?

Comment: The fact that a connected manifold  is orientable means that you can provide each tangent space with an orientation so that they are all consistent on any connected chart (fixing an orientation on $\Bbb R^n$, the chart gives you orientations on the tangent spaces).

Comment: So the solution you proprose is totally different from the one I posed, right? When you talk about orientation on tangent spaces, which 'orientation technique' you re using? Ordered basis? I don't know any of this but I'm trying to learn so I can solve this exercise. My book has almost no background in these things. I have no idea of what to do with the invertible maps.

Comment: I've edited to give a different proof using volume forms and pullback.